# getting property name of php object

Tags: php, object

If i have a php object:

```
  stdClass Object
 (
[userAttributes] => stdClass Object
    (
        [dog] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => Canine
                [required] => *
                [options] => 
                [size] => 
            )

        [cat] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => Feline
                [required] => *
                [options] => 
                [size] => 
            )
       )
 )
```

without doing a foreach loop, is it possible to print the value of the children of userAttributes.  I want to print "dog" and "cat".

if this was an array:

```
  $userAttributes['dog'] = array('type'=>'Canine'.....);
```

i could do key($userAttributes) and get the word dog. is there a php function that does the same thing as key  on objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$properties = get_object_vars( new yourFunction() );

print_r( $properties );
```

Also you can try (array) $obj cast to array as:

`var_dump((array) $obj);`

Comment: yea, that prints everything.  I want to print just the word "dog" or "cat".

Comment: Try print_r( $properties['dog']);

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
print_r($yourObject->userAttributes->dog);
```

EDIT:

```
print_r(array_keys($yourObject->userAttributes)); // will print dog, cat
```

https://www.php.net/array_keys